# File upload directly to S3

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to upload a file being uploaded via a form (eg, `request.getPart("someimage")`) directly to AWS S3 without having to first `write("/somelocaldir")` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get input stream from part

`InputStream inputStream = request.getPart("someimage").getInputStream()`

and then copy its content directly to AWS using SOAP

```
AmazonS3 amazonClient;
...
amazonClient.putObject(bucketName, key, inputStream, new ObjectMetadata());
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for. ill try it immediately. thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can upload file to AWS S3 using REST web service.
You can visit this link for more.
[File upload directly to S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146581/file-upload-directly-to-s3)

Comment: i mean, can you do it without first having to save the file from the form upload?

Comment: Yes. Please refer the link

Comment: the link is to *this* question.